# AngularJS $http post brokes the URL

Tags: json, angularjs, url, post

When I post the data in AngularJS via $http service, the form data is appended before my actual URL. As a result whether my post is successfull or not, I am redirected to my default route page.

Normally my URL format is like following,

```
http://localhost:4695/#/system/home/dashboard
```

When I post the form, it becomes like,

`http://localhost:4695/?companyFullName=&name=&position=#/system/home/dashboard`

This is how I post my form.

```
$http.post('http://localhost:2795/api/company', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My form tag has the following action attribute.

```
action="#"
```

I basically removed the `action` attribute and I am no longer having data in my URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.formParams = {
    ...
}

$http.post('http://localhost:2795/api/company',$.param($scope.formParams),{headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response){
    [Success Stuff Here]
},function(response){
    [Error Stuff Here]
});
```

Uses jQuery's `$.param` function to package up a form's data.